# Editable table / grid in asp.net with VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, aspxgridview

I'm a front-end dev, working with a VB developer to create a web application for entering fields of data: names, objectives and due dates.

**Our client** wants the data to be entered like an Excel spreadsheet: tabbing through multiple fields and entering the data. And then that inputted data gets outputted as a grid or table elsewhere to view / approve.

I work mostly in CSS/JS/PHP, and I'm pretty new to .ASPX. We are working in a **.NET 4.0 framework with VB** running on the back end to connect to SQL Server. On the **front end we have .ASPX web forms along with CSS/JS.**

**Please Note:** this is **NOT** an MVC or Core framework, but an older 4.0 .NET framework.

We've tried multiple options, but none of these work the way our client wants. I've tried this both as `<asp:Table>` with rows of `<input>` fields, and also as a `<table>` of `<asp:TextBox>` input fields. But we've run into problems both ways. We also tried a `<asp:GridView>` but that didn't work either. It was only Read-only, not editable. And it would only let you edit one row at a time. Client wanted entire table/grid to be editable. Sample of code for one below. The problem with this is that each ID is a different name: TextBox1, TextBox2, etc. And that doesn't work for the VB to save records to the database.

**Has anyone built a similar web application? What has worked for you?**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div class="obj-table">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="label name" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="label" runat="server" Text="Objective"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="label" runat="server" Text="Due Date"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="checkbox" runat="server" Text="Approved"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Name" CssClas="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Descrp" CssClas="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DueDate" CssClas="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server"/>
                </td>

                <%-- use this for when we need a drop down menu 
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>--%>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the grid view element that will automate your desired operations in sync with asp sql data source object

Comment: Thanks Amin, we originally tried that, but do not like that GridView only lets you edit one row at a time. Trying to find a different way to input the data, maybe GridView would work for output.

Comment: So you need to edit as many items as you want in the same time?

Comment: Yes, actually we were able to create an array and send a GridView with template fields containing text boxes through it. so that seems to be working. Thank you.